# how to directly access appfabric cache without proxy?

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

Start to learn and use appfabric cache.

From the whitepaper, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg186017%28v=azure.10%29.aspx, it says:
Bulk get calls result in better network utilization.Direct cache access is much faster than proxies (ASP.NET, WCF).

I am not sure what this means. What is a proxy in appfabric world?

We do websites base on asp.net/mvc, so if we write some logic to access our abpfabric cluster, it will be called from asp.net/mvc code?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [document refernced by that page](http://www.griddynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/af_cache_benchmarking_1.4.pdf) it explains what is meant by caching:

> In some cases, the cache client is wrapped and accessed via a proxy
>   with additional application or domain logic. Oftentimes, performance
>   of such applications is much different from the Windows Server
>   AppFabric Cache cluster itself. The goal of the tests in this category
>   is to show performance of a middle tier application with additional
>   logic and compare it with performance of direct access to the cache.
>
> To accomplish the goal, a simple WCF application was implemented that
>   provided access to the cache and contained additional logic of
>   populating the cache from an external data source if the requested
>   object is not yet in the cache.

The document contains details on how this affected performance, but if you need more detail the [source code used is available](http://www.griddynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/AppFabric-Cache-Benchmarking-Source.zip).

Using the [DataCacheFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacachefactory%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) (and/or [AppFabric Session provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361709%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)) from your MVC site will access the cache cluster directly, once you've granted access to the Application Pool user.